# select an element inside an xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt

i have the following xml:

```
<group> 
 <cont cont-type="author"> 
    <name>abc</name> 
 </cont>
 <cont cont-type="editor"> 
    <name>cba</name> 
 </cont> 
</group>
```

i want to be able to select editors or authors based on a parameter so i can call the proper template, ex:

```
<xsl:if test="$cont_type='editor'">
    <xsl:call-template name="editors"/>
</xsl:if>
```

so i want to be able to select the  with cont_type = editor inside the template named **editor**, how would i select the path to the  node ?

here is my editors template :

```
<xsl:template name="editors">
    <xsl:if test="exists(cont[@cont-type='editor'])">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="cont[@cont-type='editor']"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

the problem is in this editors template, i can't reach the ***cont*** element because it's path isn't specified, and in my document i have more than one  ***group*** element with different paths.

Comment: Try `<xsl:if test="@cont_type='editor'">`

Comment: Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. -- Also show how you need to use this: we don't know what your "template named editor" looks like.

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense to me, because of lack of context. See: [mcve]

Comment: Qais, See a complete solution in my answer, and note that you don't need to use named templates at all (this is actually not recommended to do in XSLT unless there is no other way -- which is almost never the case).

Answer (score 0):

Does this XSLT approximate your needs?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/group">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cont[@cont-type='author']">
    <xsl:call-template name="authors"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cont[@cont-type='editor']">
    <xsl:call-template name="editors"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This code calls the templates named `authors` or `editors` on the appropriate match.

Unfortunately you cannot pass the value of `cont-type` directly to `xsl:call-template`, because in XSLT-1.0 its `select=""` attribute requires a QName.

So, for example, the following is impossible:

```
<xsl:template match="cont[@cont-type='editor' or @cont-type='author']">
  <xsl:call-template name="{concat(@cont-type,'s')}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

If you would like to customize your output based on a parameter passed to the `xsl:stylesheet` via the XSLT processor, you'd have to define an `xsl:param` at the root level, in this case named `JSPparam`. The decision which template to call is made by an `xsl:choose` considering all `xsl:when test="$JSPparam=..."`.

I included the XPath in the `xsl:call-template` with `xsl:with-param` with the parameter of `what`. So the XPath is received in the corresponding templates with `xsl:param name="what" />` which can be accessed with the `$` prefix for further use (I used `xsl:copy-of` for illustration).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="JSPparam" select="''" />

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/group">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$JSPparam = 'author'">
        <xsl:call-template name="authors">
          <xsl:with-param name="what" select="cont[@cont-type = 'author']" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$JSPparam = 'editor'">
        <xsl:call-template name="editors">
          <xsl:with-param name="what" select="cont[@cont-type = 'editor']" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="authors">
    <xsl:param name="what" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="$what" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="editors"> 
    <xsl:param name="what" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="$what" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think you are missing the "*based on a parameter*" part of the question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I'm not sure that 'parameter' really means `parameter`. Let's wait for a comment by the author :-)

Comment: my xsl template is used from JSPs by calling it and passing a parameter that states what type of contributers you want : editor, author.
then the XSL file chooses a template based on the param value.

Comment: @Qais: I added a parameter solution to my answer. This parameter is passed **to** the XSL and **not inside** the XSL as in the previous version of my answer.

Comment: your new answer is exactly how my xsl file is, but the problem is not it.
the problem comes after calling the authors or editors templates, because inside them i can't use the <cont> element without specifying the whole path which i don't have

Comment: @Qais: I did another modification to my answer which now provides the `cont` elements in the corresponding templates.

Comment: that is fine, but what happens if i have the following paths to the `cont` element :

1) book/abstract/group/cont
2) book/chapter/group/cont
3)article/meta/group/cont

and `cont` could be `cont-type='editor'` or `cont-type='author'` ??

Comment: @Qais: Use `//cont[@cont-type = 'author']` and `//cont[@cont-type = 'editor']` instead to access all `cont` elements globally.

Comment: the problem is i don't want to access all `cont` elements in the document, i want to specify which ones to select because they have different uses

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pType" select="'author'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="group/cont[@cont-type = $pType]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="cont">
    <xsl:element name="{@cont-type}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML fragment** (surrounded by a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<groups>
    <group>
        <cont cont-type="author">
            <name>abc</name>
        </cont>
        <cont cont-type="editor">
            <name>cba</name>
        </cont>
    </group>
    <group>
        <cont cont-type="author">
            <name>def</name>
        </cont>
    </group>
</groups>
```

**the wanted actions** (templates matching `group/cont[@cont-type = $pType]` **are applied** and do whatever they are supposed to do) are performed, resulting in this case in:

```
<author>
   <name>abc</name>
</author>
<author>
   <name>def</name>
</author>
```

**If we modify the definition of the global parameter** `$pType` to:

```
 <xsl:param name="pType" select="'editor'"/>
```

**then again we get the expected, correct result:**

```
<editor>
   <name>cba</name>
</editor>
```

**Do note**:

In the "real case" you would most likely have two different templates:

```
<xsl:template match="cont[@cont-type = 'author']">
  .   .   .   .   .
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="cont[@cont-type = 'editor']">
  .   .   .   .   .
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: that is fine, but what happens if i have the following paths to the cont element : 1) book/abstract/group/cont 2) book/chapter/group/cont 3)article/meta/group/cont and cont could be cont-type='editor' or cont-type='author' ??

Comment: i need a way that makes my templates as general as possible to apply to all paths and if the XML file structure changes it should do the job. is that even possible ?

Comment: what i meant by apply to all paths is not selecting all the `cont` elements in the document but rather select the wanted ones based on the path provided. and yet make the template general so that it can apply to any provided path. i know it may sound ambiguous but that is the case i'm dealing with :)

Comment: @Qais, Re: and yet make the template general so that it can apply to any provided path -- this is contrary to the spirit of XSLT, where it is recommended to have many, but specific templates, and let the XSLT processing model decide which template to select. You can read a good XSLT book or watch an online training course. The few very generic templates that are used are for copying the (structure of) the whole document, such as the identity rule.

Comment: In my XSL file i handle each path to the `cont` element with a different template, but my boss asked me to find a way that makes the file as general as possible to handle all possible paths to `cont`, and asked to make sure it will also handle new paths if they exist in the future.
i assumed that it will be impossible but he kept asking for a solution.

Comment: @Qais, In case you want to call a template for each new type, you won't have any generality at all. Such generality can be achieved by a general `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and adding new templates that match new `@cont-type` values, as these appear in the future. Thus the basic processing remains general, but one adds new specific templates as the need arises.

Comment: now i can tell him that i've done my best and tried to do what he wanted but it's not possible, as i told him from the beginning. thank very much :)

Comment: @Qais, It *is* possible to write generic and polymorphic code in XSLT -- this is what `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is for. When the programmer writes this instruction, he doesn't know what templates will be selected for execution as result of this instruction. And in fact, this instruction generally may select for execution templates, that were not written at the time this stylesheet was deployed, but were /will be written in the future.